Negative \smallskip, \medskip and \bigskip
My attempt
I've tried creating commands for negative \smallskip, \medskip and \bigskip. I did
\def\minusSmallskip{\vspace*{-\smallskipamount}}
\def\minusMedskip{\vspace*{-\medskipamount}}
\def\minusBigskip{\vspace*{-\bigskipamount}}

Why?
The goals of these commands is to add "elastic" negative spaces around when some elements don't fit in the page and just a little space is needed.
The idea to use "elastic" space instead of \vspace{-x mm} is to have a better output.
Issues
These commands behave sometimes strangely.
For instance, in the following MWE, the command \minusSmallskip has no impact on the spacing between the text and the dotted line but has side effects:

in the first case, it "cancels" the dotted line
in the second case, it changes the place where the line is cut.

Here is the code
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[height = 7cm, width = 7cm]{geometry}

\def\minusSmallskip{\vspace*{-\smallskipamount}}
\def\minusMedskip{\vspace*{-\medskipamount}}
\def\minusBigskip{\vspace*{-\bigskipamount}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand \tightdotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .33em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
WITHOUT NEGATIVE SPACE:

This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
\tightdotfill

WITH NEGATIVE SPACE:

This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.\minusSmallskip
\tightdotfill

This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. \minusSmallskip
\tightdotfill
\end{document}


Questions

Is there a better way to creat commands for negative \smallskip, \medskip and \bigskip?
Why in my case are there these unwanted side effects?


do you really want the negative space added no matter what? so, e.g., the negative space might be added at the top of a page?

I deleted previous comments,  you are adding vertical !!) space not horizontal so it has no effect on the line breaking at all, the only differnce is whether or not you have a word space in the source before the leaders. You are then adding negative space bwtween the lines so the lines are too close together.

I've added a section "Why ?" in my question to answer you. Thank you.

it still is not clear what your intended effect is here you write "elastic" in quotes assuming that we can guess what it means, but you are using fixed lengths not rubber glue with stretch and shrink components and you are using vertical??? spacing midway through a line so not adjusting the space between the elements on the line, but just moving the lines off the normal baseline spacing.

It is easier to see the spacing if you use the Medskip rather than SmallSkip as you get this output with the lines overlapping is the inter-line space what you intended to be changing here? I am guessing not but you are only posting code and saying the output is not as you expected, you are not saying what you expected, and honestly I can't guess.

You do not say what effect you wanted to achieve, the two leaders arrangements shown are unrelated to the skips added:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[height = 7cm, width = 7cm]{geometry}

\def\minusSmallskip{\vspace*{-\smallskipamount}}
\def\minusMedskip{\vspace*{-\medskipamount}}
\def\minusBigskip{\vspace*{-\bigskipamount}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand \tightdotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .33em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
WITHOUT NEGATIVE SPACE:

This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
\tightdotfill


This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.%
\tightdotfill


\end{document}

In the first line you have a word space before the leaders which can not fit on the line so the line breaks after a and you get test.<space><leaders> on the second line.
If you avoid adding the space before the leaders (here with %) then it does just fit on the line, but the line is very tight so the leaders hardly stretch at all, and if they ever stretch to less than 0.33em then no . box will be used, so while there is a thin space from the leaders after test. the space is too thin to fit in a leaders .
In your examples with the skip in the first one you have deleted the space after . so it is exactly like the example here. In the second one the space is actually lost by the space adjustment around vspace (which moves a space character before \vspace to after it, and then merges white space..
As you added vertical space (did you intend to add horizontal space?) mid line the spaces are saved in a vadjust node and inserted between the lines after line breaking occurs, so  your "This is a test" lines are closer together than normal, less than the normal baseline spacing by smallskipamount.
